# Uploaded file fails to save with no exception thrown in Java - Jersey

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to upload a file to a restful - Jersey web service deployed on Tomcat server that is a receives uploaded files as multipart . It works fully correct on Windows OS but on Linux the file fails to save with no exception thrown from the following saving method :

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadProductImage(
        @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition cdh,
        @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataBodyPart body
) {
    FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();
    String fileName;

    try {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/files"));

        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).entity(gson.toJson(cdh.getName())).build();
}
```

The multipart variable is already declared in the web.xml file as :

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

As seen in the code the target path is "/home/files".
I'm sure that the path exists and I already tried to change the owner of the target file to the tomcat group , and granted all the permissions to the path without any results.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: *I'm sure that the path exists* I would doubt that you have permission if it does exist.  Please show the code that catches your exception

Comment: Where and what is `uploadedInputStream` set to? If it does not open the file, then the displayed would not work

Comment: I am showing the whole method in this update, and since it is upload the file may not exist previously.

Comment: OK, I can not see anything obvious in your code, so I would suggest that you debug it / or add some debug statements to make sure it is being called and to what point it is getting to

Comment: I have already stated that it is correctly working on windows , this implies that it is not returning any sort of internal errors , plus if the problem is simple I wouldn't post it on SO. the file is sent correctly  I have tested that.

Comment: OK dude, What the hell is wrong with people,  just trying to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much , I really appreciate it , believe me I have been on this for the last 3 days , forgive my impatience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after working on this I found out that file write fails or permission errors are not thrown as exceptions , the code would work normally , and in this case what can be done to solve this type of problem is the following:

1. Since the path is outside the war body it has to be indicated to within the server.xml file in the tomcat directory.
2. The directory group has to be same as Tomcat group , it can be changed through chgrp command in linux terminal.
3. Permission has to be granted to the directory's group using the chmod command in linux.